# Flutter App stop working after apk flutter install

Tags: android, flutter

My app works well when I do development debug. However, when I do flutter build and flutter install the apk to the device,  clicking on the app, just says stopped working!

#### Dependencies

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
 
 flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+3
  flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.11.0+2
  cloud_functions: ^0.3.0+1
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  rxdart: ^0.22.0
  intl: ^0.15.8
  moment: ^0.0.1
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.0"
  braintree: ^0.1.2
  dio: ^2.1.3
```

#### Error or warning I get during the build:

```
Note: C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.11.0+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-0.11.0+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\cloudfirestore\CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.4.0+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Beside that, no other real error logs.

What can be the solution to this?

Here is my app-level gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '3'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And yes I have internet permission for my AndroidManifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

So what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are u using android 9 phone to install the app?

Comment: Funny thing! I was developing with vs code! If I build with release on Android studio, all works fine. But if I build with flutter build apk, it doesn't. Never have I ever been happy with Android Studio like today :)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue with release version of my app.
The debug version was working fine, but not the release one.
When I attached the physical device, and run in release mode from Android Studio, I noticed that it fails when trying to write (locally) a downloading file from firestore.

1. Add path_provider: ^0.4.1
2. import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
3. Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
   final File file = File("${tempDir.path}/$fileName");